# How to prove that $\det(A)$ can be expressed as a $n \times n$ determinant with entries $\operatorname{tr}(A^k)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ non-singular matrix with real entries. How can I prove the following equation? Any references would be helpful. 
$$ \det(A) = \frac 1{n!} \left| \begin{array}{cccccc}\operatorname{tr}(A) & 1 & 0 & \cdots &  \cdots & 0 \\ \operatorname{tr}(A^2) & \operatorname{tr}(A) & 2 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ \operatorname{tr}(A^3) & \operatorname{tr}(A^2) & \operatorname{tr}(A) & 3 & & \vdots \\ \vdots & & & & & n-1 \\ \operatorname{tr}(A^n) & \operatorname{tr}(A^{n-1}) &  \operatorname{tr}(A^{n-2}) & \cdots & \cdots & \operatorname{tr}(A)            \end{array}\right|$$

Comment: @DietrichBurde yes.

Comment: why is this helpful for you? What is the background for this? What have you tried on your part? do you immediately see this for a $2\times 2$ matrix?

Comment: This looks like a result of the Leverrier-Faddejev algorithm. At the same time, the matrix is part of the system of Newton identities relating the power sums of the eigenvalues to the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Newton identities relating power sums of eigenvalues $s_k=tr(A^k)$ to the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial $\chi_A(t)=t^n+c_1t^{n-1}+\dots+c_{n-1}t+c_n$ with $c_n=(-1)^n\det(A)$ read as

\begin{align}
  s_1 &= -c_1,\\
  s_2 &= -c_1 s_1 - 2 c_2,\\
  s_3 &= -c_1 s_2 - c_2 s_1 - 3 c_3,\\
  s_4 &= -c_1 s_3 - c_2 s_2 - c_3 s_1 - 4 c_4, \\
         & {} \  \  \vdots\\
  s_n &= -c_1 s_{n-1}-\dots-c_{n-1} s_1 - n c_n
\end{align}

which can be written as a matrix-vector system

$$-\begin{bmatrix}
s_1\\s_2\\s_3\\\vdots\\s_{n-1}\\s_n
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&\dots&0&0\\
s_1&2&0&\dots&0&0\\
s_2&s_1&3&&0&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&&&&\vdots\\
s_{n-2}&s_{n-3}&s_{n-4}&\dots&n-1&0\\
s_{n-1}&s_{n-2}&s_{n-3}&\dots&s_1&n
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
c_1\\c_2\\c_3\\\vdots\\c_{n-1}\\c_n
\end{bmatrix}$$

or

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1\\0\\0\\0\\\vdots\\0\\0
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0&\dots&0&0\\
s_1&1&0&0&\dots&0&0\\
s_2&s_1&2&0&\dots&0&0\\
s_3&s_2&s_1&3&&0&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&&&&\vdots\\
s_{n-1}&s_{n-2}&s_{n-3}&s_{n-4}&\dots&n-1&0\\
s_n&s_{n-1}&s_{n-2}&s_{n-3}&\dots&s_1&n
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\c_1\\c_2\\c_3\\\vdots\\c_{n-1}\\c_n
\end{bmatrix}$$

Now apply Cramers rule to the computation of $c_n$ to obtain the stated formula.

---

Note that the solution of this triangular system constitutes the computational core of the Leverrier-Faddejev algorithm for the (mostly) division free computation of the characteristic polynomial of a matrix.

Answer (score 3):

Determinants and traces are invariant and everything is polynomial, so it is enough to check it for diagonal matrices.